# Submit antd form when modal is closed

Tags: reactjs, forms, modal-dialog, antd

I have a form inside a modal and would like to submit the form using the modal's ok button.

Since the submit button is then inside the modal but outside the form, I'm not sure how I would trigger the form's onFinish.

*modal logic*

```
const [isEditModalVisible, setIsEditModalVisible] = useState(false);
const showEditModal = () => {
  setIsEditModalVisible(true);
};
const handleEditOk = async (values) => {
  setIsEditModalVisible(false);
};
const handleEditCancel = () => {
  setIsEditModalVisible(false);
};
```

*form submit*

```
const handleEditFormSubmit = async (values) => {
  const name = values.name;
  const description = values.description;
  await updateProduct(name, description);
};
```

*modal and form*

```
<Modal
  title="Edit"
  visible={isEditModalVisible}
  onOk={handleEditOk}
  onCancel={handleEditCancel}
  okText="Confirm"
  cancelText="Cancel"
>
  <Form layout="vertical" onFinish={(values) => handleEditFormSubmit(values)}>
    <Form.Item
      name="name"
      label={<h5>Name</h5>}
      rules={[{ required: true }]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
    <Form.Item
      name="description"
      label={<h5>Description</h5>}
      rules={[{ required: true }]}
    >
      <Input />
    </Form.Item>
  </Form>
</Modal>;
```

Comment: You could think of using controlled values (https://ant.design/components/form/#components-form-demo-customized-form-controls) together with a callback function that you call `onOk` before closing the modal

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I've tried using the okButtonProps and couldn't do it. I ended up using a trick (just the relevant code is below, I omitted the imports and the component around):

```
   //code
 const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);

  const handleOk = () => {
    if (ref.current) {
      ref.current.click();
    }
  }
    <Modal open={visible} onCancel={onClose}
      title="Add stuff"
      destroyOnClose
      onOk={handleOk}
    >
      <Form
        onFinish={handleFormSubmit}
        className={styles.thirdStep}
      >
        <Row gutter={16}>
          <Col span={12}>
            <Form.Item label="Author" name="author" rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Please input an author' }]}>
              <Input />
            </Form.Item>
          </Col>
        </Row>
       //This is the solution basically
        <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
          <Button ref={ref} htmlType="submit" style={{ display: 'none'}} />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>

    </Modal>
```

So the basic idea is that your real submit button is not displayed, but referenced and when the user clicks okay you forward the event to your hidden submit => all good.